# optaplanner bin packing result not optimal

Tags: optaplanner, or-tools

I'm a new to optaplanner. trying to implemete a bin packing solution to packing ecomcerce order items into carton containers, we have different containers size to hold all items.

from optaplanner,  i'm follow the example case of cloudbalance to implement this bin packing. https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/use-cases-and-examples/cloud-balancing/cloud-balancing.html

when I fist run out the result.  seems not a optimized solution ,  not sure where is wrong in code.

```java
public void run() throws IOException {
    SolverFactory<CartonizationSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
            .withSolutionClass(CartonizationSolution.class)
            .withEntityClasses(OrderItem.class)
            .withConstraintProviderClass(CartonizationConstraintProvider.class)
            .withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig().withUnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit(5L)));

    Solver<CartonizationSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
    CartonizationSolution solution = load();
    CartonizationSolution solvedSolution = solver.solve(solution);
    ScoreManager<CartonizationSolution, HardSoftScore> scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
    ScoreExplanation<CartonizationSolution, HardSoftScore> cartonizationSolutionHardSoftScoreScoreExplanation = scoreManager.explainScore(solution);
    System.out.println(scoreManager.getSummary(solution));
    System.out.println("Planning items: " + solution.getOrderItems().size());
    System.out.println("Planning cartons: " + solution.getCartonRange().size());
    System.out.println("\nSolved CartonizationSolution:\n"
            + toDisplayString(solvedSolution));
}
```

```
Total Container be grouped: 4
    Type: Small -> 4
CartonContainer#Small#3: 8 items
    Volume Usage 97.005356% 13037520/13440000
    Weight Usage 34.233334% 5135/15000
CartonContainer#Small#1: 10 items
    Volume Usage 99.417336% 13361690/13440000
    Weight Usage 24.633333% 3695/15000
CartonContainer#Small#4: 11 items
    Volume Usage 75.845314% 10193610/13440000
    Weight Usage 27.333334% 4100/15000
CartonContainer#Small#2: 12 items
    Volume Usage 99.58103%  13383690/13440000
    Weight Usage 91.64% 13746/15000

Total Volum: 53760000
```

```
public class CartonizationConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{
                requiredWeightTotal(constraintFactory),
                requiredVolumeTotal(constraintFactory),
                computerCost(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    Constraint requiredWeightTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(OrderItem.class)
                .groupBy(OrderItem::getContainer, sum(OrderItem::getWeight))
                .filter((container, requiredWeight) -> requiredWeight > container.getMaxWeight())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                        (container, requiredWeight) -> requiredWeight - container.getMaxWeight())
                .asConstraint("requiredWeightTotal");
    }

    Constraint requiredVolumeTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(OrderItem.class)
                .groupBy(OrderItem::getContainer, sum(OrderItem::getVolume))
                .filter((container, requiredVolume) -> requiredVolume > container.getMaxVolume())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                        (container, requiredVolume) -> requiredVolume - container.getMaxVolume())
                .asConstraint("requiredVolumeTotal");
    }

    Constraint computerCost(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(CartonContainer.class)
                .ifExists(OrderItem.class, equal(Function.identity(), OrderItem::getContainer))
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, CartonContainer::getMaxVolume)
                .asConstraint("overallVolume");
    }
}
```

Similar data running with google's OR-Tools.

I can get bellow result.

```
Number of Items be planning:  41
Number of Carton be planning:  30
<generator object cartonize.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1057f3530>
Bin number #0 Small
  Items packed: 9
  Total weight: 42% 6.2909999999999995 / 15.0
  Total volume: 99% 13320.85 / 13440.0

Bin number #15 Small
  Items packed: 14
  Total weight: 78% 11.686000000000002 / 15.0
  Total volume: 99% 13269.66 / 13440.0

Bin number #25 Medium
  Items packed: 18
  Total weight: 58% 8.698999999999998 / 15.0
  Total volume: 99% 23386.0 / 23520.0


Number of bins used: 3
Total volume 50400.0
Time =  1138  milliseconds
```

Should a close solution result as OR Tools, as the total volume is lower

Answer (score 0):

[Please enable subpillar change and swap moves.](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#pillarMoveSelectors)